# Run some code before click in knockout

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

There is a data bind onClick within a div like so :

```
data-bind='click: $root.addTable'
```

Is it possible to run some javascript before the click is invoked and if it satisfys a certain condition not to invoke the click ?

Something like ? :

```
<div id="onThisClick" data-bind='click: $root.addTable'></div>

$("#onThisClick").delegate("#all", "click", function() {
if(isTrue){
}
else {
 //run data binding as normal
}
}
```

I'm performing some validation and need to pass a value to the invoked javascript function.

Comment: I don't think what you're trying is possible.. Why can't you perform your logic within the function you call when "click" is invoked?

Comment: @Rune Vejen Petersen ive updated question

Answer (score 2):

Why not just do the check in the method that is called?

```
<div class="button" data-bind="click: $root.addTable">Click</div>

// in javascript
function RootViewModel() {
    this.addTable = function() {
        if(!condition) {
            return; 
        }
        // jumps out when a condition is met

        // do what you're supposed to do here
    }
}
```

No need to complicate it more than a condition and a return.

---

Edit: Getting a value from HTML is easy with jQuery if you're already using it. Here is an example if you're using a hidden field (you can retrieve it with [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
<input type="hidden" id="myvalue" value="true"></input>

// in javascript code, select the element by it's id
if ($("#myvalue").val()) return;

// plain vanilla JS is a bit more verbose
if (document.getElementById("myvalue").value === "true") return;
```

You can play around with [*this jsfiddle*](http://jsfiddle.net/BHY2E/1/) with the idea.

Comment: +1 This is what I meant about invoking your logic inside the function you call in "click"

Comment: @Spoike the condition is dependent on a javascript variable within the html file. The condition code itself is in a separate file. This is why I'm trying to call the condition before its invoked as I cant seem to figure out how to pass a variable value from the html file to the javascript file.

Comment: @user470184 not quite sure how your value is stored in the html file, but I updated with a hidden form input field. also made a jsfiddle that demonstrates this

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that your problem is that you have called a function defined in `$root` but you want to access a property of `$data` (the view model at the time of binding). Knockout calls the bound function using the `apply()` method and passes your current view model as the first parameter. So your `$data` is available as `this` within in your function (when it's called via the click event).

Answer (score -1):

I've heard of knockoutJS and I'm interested in learning about it, but in this one instance, it's not doing you any good. JQuery, on the other hand:

```
$(function() {
    $root = $("#root");
    $root.addTable = function() {
        $root.html("Hooray!");
    };

    $("#onThisClick").on("click", function() {
       $root.html("");
       if($("#theText").val().match(/sad/)){
           alert("Must not be sad to see table!");
       }
       else {
          $root.addTable();
       }
   });

});
```

Seems to be working just fine.  Any values you need to pass to `addTable()` can be accessed using your other HTML5 `data` attributes with no problem.  [Check out the fiddle, and fork it to make it work for you](http://jsfiddle.net/amullins/sGeS6/2/).

Comment: -1. Your answer completely sidesteps the question of doing a thing *before the knockout click*. Throwing jQuery at a problem is not a one-size-fits all solution. *You even point out that you don't know what you are talking about* before you start! Also, its not Knockout that isn't "doing any good", its the guy trying to do something that doesn't even make sense.